How to plot the solution of an equation in 3D - Mathematica
I'm trying to plot the solution of the equation: Prime[x] + Prime[y] == Prime[z] as a cloud of points, but the graphics is plotted empty. Does anybody know how to plot the solution points $(x,y,z)$ correctly?
The code:
L = 20;
SL = Solve[Prime[x] + Prime[y] == Prime[z] && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 1 && 
           x <= L && y <= L && z <= L, {x, y, z}, Integers]
Plot3D[SL, {x, -1, 10}, {y, -1, 10}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]


Please check the document of ListPointPlot3D and Solve and ReplaceAll (/.) carefully: https://i.sstatic.net/H3k8ItAO.png

Graphics3D[Point[{x, y, z} /. SL], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]


as a cloud of points,

L = 20;
SL = SolveValues[
  Prime[x] + Prime[y] == Prime[z] && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 1 && 
   x <= L && y <= L && z <= L, {x, y, z}, Integers];
 ListPointPlot3D[SL, 
                 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
                 BaseStyle -> 14, 
                 PlotStyle -> Red]



Nice solution. I tried (Mathematica v12.2) to increase value L=30 but got error message "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." Any idea why?

@UlrichNeumann sorry, I do not know why V 12.2 did not solve. My only guess is that it must be they must improved the solver since then.

Thanks for your answer!
